# How to get data from two different tables using stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server-2008, function, stored-procedures, join

I am new to functions so am having a bit starting trouble here

I have two tables like this

**Bugs**

```
BugID | Title | ProjectName | CreatedBy
```

**BugHistory**

```
BughistoryID | BugID | Assignedto | ToStatus | FromStatus
```

**EmployeeTable**

```
EmployeeID | EmployeeName |
```

`[AssignedTo]` column from `BugHistory` is a foreign key for `[EmployeeId]` in `EmployeeTable`.

I want a select statement where I have to show the bugs table in gridview with `[AssignedTo]` and `[Tostatus]` columns from `BugHistory` table. How can I use functions for this both procedure s any ideas please?

In `Assigned to` column I want the name of the employee - how can I map this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want this:

```
SELECT b.BugId
    , b.Title
    , b.ProjectName
    , b.CreatedBy
    , e.EmployeeName As AssignedTo
    , bh.ToStatus
FROM Bugs b
INNER JOIN BugHistory bh
    ON b.bugid = bh.bugid
INNER JOIN Employee e
    ON bh.AssignedTo = e.EmployeeId
```

Comment: @blufeet CreatedBy is also an foreign key to EmployeeID

Comment: @anilkumar what do you mean no luck?  Can you create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with some sample data?